# a list of list value populated in struts2 iterator

Tags: list, struts2

For my case, it is a little bit trickier. I just have another list in person object, it is called state. like below:

```
public class People {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<State> states;
    // Plus setters/getters
}

public class State {
    private int id;
private String stateAbbr;
private String stateName;
public State (String stateAbbr, String stateName) {
this.stateAbbr = stateAbbr;
this.stateName = stateName;
}
   // Plus setters/getters
}
```

Action class:

```
public class PersonAction extends ActionSupport {
private List<People> peopleList;

public List<People> getPeopleList() {
    return peopleList;
}

public void setPeopleList(List<People> peopleList) {
    this.peopleList = peopleList;
}

//Initial Load method
@Override
public String execute() {
    peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();

    int alpha = 65;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        People people = new People();
        people.setId(i);
        people.setName(String.valueOf((char)alpha++));
        peopleList.add(people);
    }

    for (People people : peopleList){
        State state = new State("BC", "BritishColumbia");
        List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
        states.add(state);
        state = new State("AC", "AppleColumbia");
        states.add(state);
        people.setStates(states);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

//Function that handles the form submit
public String updatePerson() {
    for(People people : peopleList) {
        System.out.println(people.getId() + ":" + people.getName());
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

JSP page

```
<s:form action="doUpdate">
    <s:iterator value="peopleList" status="stat" var="people">
        <s:textfield value="%{#people.name}"
            name="peopleList[%{#stat.index}].name" />
        <s:iterator value="states" status="stateStatus" var="personState">
            <s:textfield value="%{#personState.stateAbbr}"
                name="peopleList[%{#stat.index}].states[%{#stateStatus.index}].stateAbbr" label="Abbr State" />
            <br />
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
    <s:submit value="Submit" />
</s:form>
```

When I submit this page, I got states is [null] in person, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state` property is a property of a specific person. In this case, you need to "connect" the state to `persons[%{#stat.index}]`, so:

```
<s:textfield ... 
    name="persons[%{#stat.index}].states[%{#stateStatus.index}]" .../>
```

The iterator status variable has an `index` property that avoids the math you're doing on the [`IteratorStatus` (docs)](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) instance:

```
<s:textfield ... name="persons[%{#stat.index}].name" />
```

<strike>Also, depending on which version of S2 you're using, you may not need the `#` character.</strike>

Comment: @user1006080 I can't really read that, but check to see what is being sent in the submission.

Comment: I just repost my question again, could you take a look again?

Comment: @user1006080 Yep. What version of S2 are you using?

Comment: @user1006080 By the way, your `People`/`persons` naming conventions are backwards; the class should be `Person`, singular, and the collection should be `people`, plural :)

Comment: I am using Struts 2 version is struts2-core-2.2.1.jar, is that right? should I try the latest version 2.2.3 ?

Comment: @user1006080 You should, but it's not the reason there's a problem with this code. If nothing else, upgrade to 2.2.1.1 for a security fix.

Comment: I don't understand singular/plural problem, but i repost my question again to make it more clear. could you please find out what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the new question:

If your `State` class doesn't have a default constructor, S2/OGNL will not be able to instantiate an empty version of the class.

Provide a default (no-argument) constructor, and the person's states list will be populated.

(Too bad both answers can't be accepted ;)

Comment: You are right, after I add no argu construtor, it works. Did this mentioned in any online struts 2 tutorial? why People entity bean doesn't need no argu construtor? and why my states with argu constructor can NOT let S2/OGNL to instantiate state class?

Comment: @user1006080 Please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so others with similar problems know the solution (and, IMO, vote them both up to reward my effort). The `People` class *has* a default constructor; every class *that doesn't define a non-default constructor* has one. Because you defined a non-default ctor in `State`, it no longer had a default (no-arg) ctor.

Comment: if i use the latest struts 2 version 2.2.3, can I remove # character?

Comment: @user1006080 It looks like I was wrong about that; the rules for when you need a `#` and when you don't are a bit fuzzy.