# Repopulating a list from JSP to action in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, type-conversion, ognl

I'm using the Struts 2 framework and I want to transfer a list of objects from Java to JSP and back to Java. Transferring to JSP works fine with the `<s:iterator>` tag. Transferring back to Java does not, my list is never populated.

I already checked these questions:

- [Repopulate ArrayList from JSP with Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650800/repopulate-an-arraylist-from-jsp-with-struts2)
- [a list of list value populated in struts2 iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897027/a-list-of-list-value-populated-in-struts2-iterator)
- [Populate Collection from Struts2 Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975883/populate-collection-from-struts2-form-submission)
- [Populate List<String> in struts2 from form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834944/populate-liststring-in-struts2-from-form-data?lq=1)

and followed their suggestions.

Here is my `Item` class (it is has more properties than just name, but I'm only showing relevant ones):

Class `Item`:

```
    private String name;

    public Item(){}

    public String getName(){ ... };
    public void setName(String newName){ ... };
```

and on my JSP I have:

```xhtml
<s:iterator value="items" status="key">
    <s:hidden name="items[%{#key.index}].name" value="%{name}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Here's the relevant part of the action class:

```
private  List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

public List<Item> getItems()
{
    System.out.println("now getting Items");
    
    if(Items == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Items is null");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Items is not null. size: " + Items.size());
    }
    
    return Items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> Items)
{
    System.out.println("now setting Items");

    Items = Items;
}
```

I'm 100% sure it has all the necessary getters and setters because the JSP is populated correctly, and when I submit my form I can actually see (with log statements) that my `getItems()` method is being called once for each item in my list (for each input field in the form). It's just weird that Struts2 is getting the list once for every hidden input field in the form, but then refuses to create an Item object and set it's name to the given value anything in it. The problem cannot be the lack of a no-args constructor.

I also added an conversion file named with `ActionName-conversion.properties` (where `ActionName` is the name of my action class) and it is in the same folder as my `ActionName.java` class.

```
Element_items = Item
CreateIfNull_items = true
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Your code is fine, you cleared also my first thought (`The problem cannot be the lack of a no-args constructor`). What is left ? Interceptor Stack. Please show it, I bet a beer the problem is there

Comment: I use the default stack (which has the param interceptor). I just tested to see if I could get a list<String> populated from my JSP (rather than a List<Item>) and this works fine. I really think there is something wrong with struts2 trying to create a new Item (or somehow not knowing the list is of type Item and thus not knowing it has to create an Item Object?).

Comment: Try removing your ActionName-conversion.properties (not needed here), if it doesn't work, please post just the declaration and initialization of your List<Item> in your Action class.

Comment: Removing the properties file did not change anything. I added the relevant parts in the action class (making, getting and setting the item list) in my question. you'll see the get method has system.outs. I actually these print statements in my console 4 times, and my item list has 4 values. Item list is not null. But the amount of elements in the list always stays 0. It is not a readonly list or something similar.

Comment: I guess `Items` is always `items`, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, copy/paste issue with the capital i, sorry. 
Hold on. It suddenly worked. I guess removing the properties file DID work. I guess my tomcat server wasn't cleaned or something? Ok so, what did that file broke that is being fixed if the file is not there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `List` or `Map` for your collection of items you can reference its elements by index without using an `ObjectTypeDeterminer`. See

> [**Built in Type Conversion Support**](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html#built-in-type-conversion-support)
>
> Type Conversion is implemented by XWork.
>
> XWork will automatically handle the most common type conversion for
> you. This includes support for converting to and from Strings for each
> of the following:
>
> - String
> - boolean / Boolean
> - char / Character
> - int / Integer, float / Float, long / Long, double / Double
> - dates - uses the SHORT format for the Locale associated with the current request
> - arrays - assuming the individual strings can be coverted to the individual items
> - collections - if not object type can be determined, it is assumed to be a String and a new ArrayList is created
>
> > Note that with arrays the type conversion will defer to the type of
> > the array elements and try to convert each item individually. As with
> > any other type conversion, if the conversion can't be performed the
> > standard type conversion error reporting is used to indicate a problem
> > occurred while processing the type conversion.
>
> - Enumerations
> - BigDecimal and BigInteger

---

If you want to use advanced type conversion using `ObjectTypeDeterminer` to determine a type of object being instantiated when populated a collection or the object that is retrieved from the collection by the key property of the element in OGNL expression you should see

> [**Collection and Map Support**](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html#collection-and-map-support)
>
> Collection and Map support provides intelligent null handling and type
> conversion for Java Collections.
>
> The framework supports ways to discover the object type for elements
> in a collection. The discover is made via an `ObjectTypeDeterminer`. A
> default implementation is provided with the framework. The Javadocs
> explain how `Map` and `Collection` support is discovered in the
> `DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer`.
>
> This `ObjectTypeDeterminer` looks at the `Class-conversion.properties` for
> entries that indicated what objects are contained within Maps and
> Collections. For Collections, such as Lists, the element is specified
> using the pattern `Element_xxx`, where `xxx` is the field name of the
> collection property in your action or object. For Maps, both the key
> and the value may be specified by using the pattern `Key_xxx` and
> `Element_xxx`, respectively.
>
> From WebWork 2.1.x, the `Collection_xxx` format is still supported and
> honored, although it is **deprecated** and will be removed eventually.
>
> Additionally, you can create your own custom `ObjectTypeDeterminer` by
> implementing the `ObjectTypeDeterminer` interface. There is also an
> optional `ObjectTypeDeterminer` that utilizes Java 5 generics. See the
> [Annotations](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/annotations.html) page for more information.

---

You can use `ActionClass-conversion.properties` and specify all properties necessary for the type conversion. If you didn't specify some properties the defaults are applied.

In your case you didn't specify a key property, i.e. `KeyProperty_items`, in this case the `id` property of the `Item` is used. If you don't have such property the conversion might fail.

There's also possible to use annotations for type conversion. See examples

- [Retrieving values from list in execute() method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23829108/573032)
- [Passing value from jsp to Action for java.util.Set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849726/573032)
- [How to get updated list values from JSP in my action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19155411/573032)
- [How to use ModelDriven to insert a value into Set Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191304/573032)

Also note to use correct syntax for field names using OGNL expression, which uses indexing by object reference, rather than referencing by collection index. This kind of indexing perfectly works for lists. It also works using advanced type conversion.

Why it's working is out of the topic of this question. Sure you can fix your properties and use advanced type conversion, or remove it and use indexed collection like a list.